# Vte: get cursor position in screen coordinates

Tags: gtk, pygtk, vte

VTE's [get_cursor_position()](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-get-cursor-position) returns "scrollback buffer" coordinates, i.e. the `y` is relative not to beginning of the screen, but to the to the beginning of the scrollback buffer. How can I get screen coordinates instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window().get_pointer()
```